# Splitting a string into variable length strings in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to do something like this:
To my subroutine, a long string comes as an input. I need to split this string into multiple strings of variable length for ex:
my string will be composed of numbers, spl characters, alphabet etc. I would like to have
byte 1, 2 together as a string
byte 3 - 30 together as another substring
byte 31 - 35 as another substring and so till the end of the string is reached?
How can I do this? Please help me out with a sample code

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yet?  That's the best way we can help.

Comment: by byte you mean character? check out http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html

Comment: By byte I mean it can be anything a metacharacter, character, number etc

Answer (score 1):

```
my @fields = unpack 'a2 a28 a4', $_;
```